# What's the closest I can come to disabling the transaction log in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a database that is regenerated daily from an external source, so I don't care about backing it up. The transaction log can grow to several gb as it is wiped and updated every day with new data.

I tried limiting the size but I started getting `The transaction log for database 'myDB' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'`

I tried setting it to SIMPLE, but the same error as above.

What can I do to ensure it doesn't break and it doesn't take up space?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best but how about executing a BACKUP LOG.

From BOL:
Transaction Log Truncation
To avoid filling up the transaction log of a database, routine backups are essential. Under the simple recovery model, log truncation occurs automatically after you back up the database, and under the full recovery model, after you back up the transaction log. However, sometimes the truncation process can be delayed. For information about identifying and responding to delaying factors, see Factors That Can Delay Log Truncation.

Note:
The BACKUP LOG WITH NO_LOG and WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY options have been discontinued. If you are using the full or bulk-logged recovery model recovery and you must remove the log backup chain from a database, switch to the simple recovery model. For more information, see Considerations for Switching from the Full or Bulk-Logged Recovery Model.

For more information about log truncation in general, see Transaction Log Truncation.